# vbscript output to text on wndows startup

Tags: vbscript, wscript.shell

I'm looking for vbscript that do the following tasks

### Script Tasks

1. execute on **startup** of the computer, 
   the way is being executed is via putting it in startup folder of windows in
   `C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
2. if output text file is exist, write down some text and exit
3. if the text file is not exist then it echo out full destination

the code is as provided, any help would be appreciated

```
'create txt.vbs
'vbscript
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
FilePath = CurrentDirectory & "\test.txt"

Existcode = objFSO.FileExists(FilePath)
' wscript.echo "FileExists code:" & Existcode

if Existcode = False then
    Existcode = objFSO.FileExists(FilePath)
    'for debugging
    wscript.echo "file not exist" & vbCrLf _
    & "FileExists code:" & Existcode

    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(FilePath,True)
    strtext = "file created:" & vbCrLf & chr(34) & "New Line" & chr(34)
    objFile.Write strtext & vbCrLf
    objFile.Close
else
    'for debugging
    wscript.echo "file exist" & vbCrLf _
    & "FileExists code:" & Existcode & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & FilePath & vbCrLf _
    & CurrentDirectory & vbCrLf
end if
wscript.echo "end"
```

when get executed by **clicking** on it, either via a **batch file**, the script works with no errors and the output is as expected

> while it's executed from `startup` folder by
>   windows, it show all echo that i set for debugging but doesn't
>   create the output file neither write to text in it, but also it read it as exist i'm not sure why

Comment: can you try by saving it in a pre-defined location like C:\temp and see its working or not

Comment: @user5612655 did that actually  (from my desktop), it works fine

Comment: if it is working fine with other folder maybe this has got something to do with creating file in that folder than script, permissions or something like that.

Comment: true, when executed as output to the desktop it work fine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the vbscript cannot write text to startup folder,
however changes are the following

```
CurrentDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
FilePath = CurrentDirectory & "\test.txt"
```

become

```
DesktopDirectory = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
FilePath = DesktopDirectory & "\test.txt"
```